# Changing URL via SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

With only a basic understanding of SQL and PHP, I've been trying to migrate a Wordpress layout built on a local server:

```
http://131...
```

to

```
ceje.webhost.uic.edu
```

Once I changed the 'siteurl' and 'home' in phpmyadmin, the styling and pictures failed to load. It seemed that before the change, it was still pulling the pictures from the locally hosted website.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but a URL change should fix this? All of the files have been uploaded to the new hosting server space, so therefore should be accessed by "ceje.webhost.uic.edu/..."?

I tried in sql query on phpmyadmin:

```
USE **databasename**;

UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://131....',       
'http://ceje.webhost.uic.edu/') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

but returns error 1064

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL    
server version for the right syntax to use near
```

edit: fixed a syntax error in the sql query, now getting back no rows return.

```
# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
```

EDIT: Solved by simply applying the following code to functions.php file.

```
update_option('siteurl','...');     
update_option('home','...');
```

Comment: missing single quote in mysql query: UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://131.193.220.64/ceje','http://ceje.webhost.uic.edu/') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

Comment: Thanks, that helped the query go through, but got back:

# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Comment: UPDATE query will return "rows affected" result, are you executing any  SELECT query after that?

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but isn't setting the update = replace syntax equivalent to a: search/replace function, therefore not needing a select query if I wish to "update" all results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When migrating the site the image urls are not changed. Granted you need to change both the site/home url for the website to even show.

When migrating a site the best thing to do is to install the following plugin.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/

This will allow you to search and replace in the database as image links will be found in many of your tables ie wp_posts where all your post data is held will have image urls in the post content for example. This plugin will search all tables for the old url and replace it with the new url you give it.

If you have hard coded any images in the files with absolute urls, then you will have to change this manually.

I have used the plugin many times successfully, but I still back up the database every time just in case and I would advise you do the same.

Comment: Should this plugin be used after the URL has been changed on Wordpress? My initial goal with the SQL query was to do so, but I'll try this plugin.

Comment: Yes once you have changed the site/home url then you can log into your dashboard and install the plugin to fix the images, let me know how you get on

Comment: Hmm, I may have done something slightly wrong. I went about changing the URL via wordpress from the local-server IP address to the subdomain, however now wp-login is not accessible.

Comment: The site/home url should stay the same on the development server. Then you migrate both the files and database to the new server. Once you have migrated, you then change the data on the production server to represent the new url for both site/home. Once changed the site should be accessible and the the dashboard would also be available. Once at this stage, you would then install the plugin.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I went and did the Search and Replace, then also updated the functions.php of my site to reflect the new URL correctly. Works well now!

Comment: @julesverne glad you got it working. That search and replace has always done the job for me.